# Compare two arrays and return the same values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$anna_array = array("soccer" => "10", "basketball" => "20", "tennis" => "30", "atletics" => "40", "volleyball" => "50");
$john_array = array("soccer" => "15", "basketball" => "15", "atletics" => "45");
```

**Explanation**

The score of Anna at Soccer is 10 and of John is 15 and so on.

I want to return the same activities in both arrays. Something like:

**Anna activities**: Soccer = 10 - Basketball = 20 - Atletics = 40.

**John activities**: Soccer = 15 - Basketball = 15 - Atletics = 45.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I appreciate that you added a clear question, but it's too broad, because you didn't include any attempt. For the first problem: iterate through the first array and for every element from the first array iterate through the second array. **If** you find an element that is in both arrays, you can add it to a third array and that would be the final result. Then you can use the first part and you can place your code inside the second loop. You can keep 2 variables `a` for Anna, and `j` for John that are 0 and during the comparison (inside the **if** block) you can increment `a` or `j`.

Comment: @Fredrico. No, it is an idea I want to use on my website to help my students to work harder.

Comment: @engineer Thank you for the explanation. I will try to solve the first problem then the second. I really need this for my students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the intersection of an array with `array_intersect_key`.

```
$anna_array = array('Soccer' => "10", 'Basketball' => "20", 'Tennis' => "30", 'Atletics' => "40", 'Volleyball' => "50");
$john_array = array('Soccer' => "15", 'Basketball' => "15", 'Atletics' => "45");

$anna_activities = array_intersect_key($anna_array, $john_array);
$john_activities = array_intersect_key($john_array, $anna_array);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/rAtS4).

Comment: Thank you very much Federico. Now to the second problem:)